# why sparse report the sizeof(bool) warning?

Tags: c, boolean, sizeof, static-analysis

I am very new to `sparse` and i am using it to clean the noise from the code. Recently, somewhere in code line:   `kzalloc(sizeof(bool) * nvhost_syncpt_nb_pts(sp), GFP_KERNEL);` I encountered this `sparse` warning:

```
warning: expression using sizeof bool
```

I wonder, why `sparse` is reporting this warning. On googling, I found that sizeof(bool) is compiler dependent which is very obvious. Please help me why this warning is raised by `sparse` which i think should not be reported ? Please correct me if i am wrong.

I am using `gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)`. Let's say bool is defined here as:

```
#if !defined(__cplusplus)
# if defined(_MSC_VER) || !defined(__STDC_VERSION__) || \
    (__STDC_VERSION__ < 199901L)
// The Visual Studio C compiler and older versions of GCC do not support C99
// and thus have no bool or stdbool.h.  Make a simple definition of bool,
// true, and false to make this deprecated interface compile in C.  Force it
// to 1 byte to have some chance of ABI compatibility between C and C++, in
// case we don't remove this.

typedef char bool;
#  define false 0
#  define true 1
# else
// In C99-compliant compilers, we can include stdbool.h to get a bool
// definition.
#  include <stdbool.h>
# endif
#endif

/**
* @}
* End addtogroup PP
*/

#endif  /* PPAPI_C_DEV_DEPRECATED_BOOL_H_ */
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look in the sparse git source tree at `evaluate.c` in:

```
static struct symbol *evaluate_sizeof(struct expression *expr)
{
    ...
    if (size == 1 && is_bool_type(type)) {
        if (Wsizeof_bool)
            warning(expr->pos, "expression using sizeof bool");
        size = bits_in_char;
    }
    ...
}
```

ant then in `parse.c`:

```
keyword_table[] = {
    ...
    { "_Bool",  NS_TYPEDEF, .type = &bool_ctype, .op = &spec_op },
    ...
};
```

you will see that every `sizeof(_Bool)` gets reported as a warning if not overridden by `Wsizeof_bool`.

Now considering your code:

```
kzalloc(sizeof(bool) * nvhost_syncpt_nb_pts(sp), GFP_KERNEL);
```

I'm not sure what our `bool` here is, but if it is the `bool` from `include/linux/types.h` : `typedef _Bool bool;` no wonder you get the warning. As for the reasoning behind the warning you seem to have figured it out by yourself:

`On googling, I found that sizeof(bool) is compiler dependent which is very obvious.`

But as additional documentation [this](http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/bool.html) may be helpful.

If you think the warning is not relevant for your code just get rid of it with `-Wno-sizeof-bool`.